# localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)

Tags: linux, ssh, hadoop

I was trying to run Hadoop in Mac OS and I get the following errors,

```
$ hstart


WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as chaklader in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
Starting secondary namenodes [macs-MacBook-Pro.local]
macs-MacBook-Pro.local: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
2018-08-14 13:59:34,949 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

I looked into the Google and find a similar post. I mentioned that Permission denied is the error, and I didn't set up `passwordless ssh` correctly. For example, ssh localhost should not ask for a password.

I run the `ssh localhost` and it did ask for the password. As a solution to the problem, it was mentioned to execute the command,

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I did that and afterward when I run the ssh localhost, I was asked for the passphrase (than the password).

```
$ ssh localhost

Enter passphrase for key '/Users/chaklader/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Last login: Tue Aug 14 14:03:30 2018 from ::1
```

The original problem was not solved. There was another post mentioned to execute the command `chmod og-wx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and after I did that, it still keeps that same.

I tried to check what is inside the id_rsa and find the info,

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa 

AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDB/1Ryk4mB2/9rxpvF21JWKBOyx+hgo572zp9ZNcLmj1FcNN9saJ0AfYcmkILowEoCKgzOCbAvapd+JsPomPMsuKD37AGvfF88YWAjKPYOg3wo5JMwIp/CEyk349satGWUy+Q99288iJcS5NKkhLEN1bMOyIpgbFFxmpCdFXNSl9UfeCN4oyndWJzmnHkI6C9mu4BWibcW3PkKkwI2HVPop14m3jRjHJvmwGzRQxp/bjUVRqSZ52KTuVMYRrCsKdd048tBHOK0ujjshpBCoedtFoXt3xP0B78WZyvgFr2Pj9DrgdFI+T7gkJUv4xbmtKfCOZR7yFVwoUtgAF5k/FC1 chaklader@macs-MacBook-Pro.local


$ cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa 

AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDB/1Ryk4mB2/9rxpvF21JWKBOyx+hgo572zp9ZNcLmj1FcNN9saJ0AfYcmkILowEoCKgzOCbAvapd+JsPomPMsuKD37AGvfF88YWAjKPYOg3wo5JMwIp/CEyk349satGWUy+Q99288iJcS5NKkhLEN1bMOyIpgbFFxmpCdFXNSl9UfeCN4oyndWJzmnHkI6C9mu4BWibcW3PkKkwI2HVPop14m3jRjHJvmwGzRQxp/bjUVRqSZ52KTuVMYRrCsKdd048tBHOK0ujjshpBCoedtFoXt3xP0B78WZyvgFr2Pj9DrgdFI+T7gkJUv4xbmtKfCOZR7yFVwoUtgAF5k/FC1 chaklader@macs-MacBook-Pro.local
```

This looks like the same info to me. What is here missed?

Comment: The two files will have exactly the same contents,`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` this is what that command achieves. It looks like you have a passphrase set, i would generate a new ssh-key with no passphrase, and add that key to authorized keys.

Comment: Why would that be helped?

Comment: because you have to enter a passphrase to log in? so you haven't set up passwordless ssh....

Comment: @alpha That's incorrect.  The command **appends** the pubkey to the authorized keys file.  It's just that the authorized keys file was empty, so after running the command the OP ended up with two identical files.

Comment: Later I kept blank for the pass phrase and it worked

Comment: In my case on Mac I had already created a key using a password. So to fix this I deleted the 'authorized_keys' file and regenerated new private key with blank password. Then the `ssh localhost` command worked without password prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key should not be protected by a password.
[Check this post for checking that](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129724/how-to-check-if-an-ssh-private-key-has-passphrase-or-not)

Are the permissions on your private key properly set?
It should be set as:

```
  chmod 600  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: The issue was the key was required a pass phrase